# pass dynamically created id to getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm trying to pass dynamically created id to getElementById but when i try to log it, it says undefined.

```
"<input type='text' class='span2' name='price' pattern='[0-9.]*' id='p'"+ field.id + "placeholder='Price' value='0' />"
```

console:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("p"+field.id).value);
console.log($("#p"+field.id).val());
```

both says undefined. what is wrong i'm doing?

Comment: Why did you do this in your html? `...id='p'+ field.id + placeholder='Price'...` Concatenating `filed.id` with `placeHolder`

Comment: What @RajaprabhuAravindasamy is trying to say is, you might try adding a space before `placeholder` so that the resulting string reads `... id='p'"+ field.id + " placeholder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you concatenated your html string is improper,

```
 ...id='p'"+ field.id..
```

So the above snippet will be evaluated to `id='p'Something` And while rendering that `something` came from `field.id` will be treated as an `attribute`.

So try to write it like,

```
"<input type='text' class='span2' name='price' pattern='[0-9.]*' id='p"+ field.id + "' placeholder='Price' value='0' />"
//------------------------------------------------------------------^----------------^
//changed the position of quotes.
```